# How to replace values in a range in a pandas dataframe with another value in the same dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I want to replace values within a range of columns in a dataframe with a corresponding value in another column if the value in the range is greater than zero.

I would think that a simple replace like this would work:

```
df = df.loc[:,'A':'D'].replace(1, df['column_with_value_I_want'])
```

But that in fact does nothing as far as I can tell except drop the `column_with_value_I_want`, which is totally unintended, and I'm not sure why that happens.

This doesn't seem to work either:

```
df[df.loc[:,'A':'D']] > 0 = df['column_with_value_I_want']
```

It returns the error: `SyntaxError: can't assign to comparison`.

This seems like it should be straightforward, but I'm at a loss after trying several different things to no avail.

The dataframe I'm working with looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,0,0,1,0,0],
                   'B' : [1,0,0,1,0,1],
                   'C' : [1,0,0,1,0,1],
                   'D' : [1,0,0,1,0,0],
                   'column_with_value_I_want' : [22.0,15.0,90.0,10.,None,557.0],})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it in Pandas per se, but it's not that difficult if you drop down to numpy.

---

If you're lucky enough so that your entire DataFrame is numerical, you can do so as follows:

```
import numpy as np

m = df.as_matrix()
>>> pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(np.logical_or(np.isnan(m), m > 0), np.tile(m[:, [4]], 5), m), 
    columns=df.columns)
    A   B   C   D   column_with_value_I_want
0   22  22  22  22  22
1   0   0   0   0   15
2   0   0   0   0   90
3   10  10  10  10  10
4   0   0   0   0   NaN
5   0   557     557     0   557
```

---

- `as_matrix` converts a DataFrame to a numpy `array`.
- `np.where` is `numpy`'s ternary conditional.
- `np.logical_or` is `numpy`'s or.
- `np.isnan` is a check if a value is not `nan`.
- `np.tile` tiles (in this case) a 2d single column to a matrix.

---

Unfortunately, the above will fail if some of your columns (even those not involved in this operation) are inherently non-numerical. In this case, you can do the following:

```
for col in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    df[col] = np.where(df[col] > 0, df[col], df.column_with_value_I_want)
```

which will work as long as the 5 relevant columns are numerical.

This uses a loop (which is frowned upon in numerical Python), but at least it does so over columns, and not rows. Assuming your data is longer than wider, it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Not sure why, but I'm getting an error when I try this: `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`. Not quite sure what to make of that.

Comment: You're welcome. Are you trying it on the DataFrame you posted here, or on a different one? If on this one - I'm stumped (worked for me). If on a different one, I'm guessing your data isn't numbers, only strings that look like numbers.

Comment: Indeed your solution works on the df I provided. Not sure why it doesn't work on mine (my df is all floats, or so it appears). I'm going to investigate a little and I'll be sure to follow up. Again, big thanks.

Comment: Again, you're welcome! Note that to make sure that your DataFrame is floating point, you can do `df = df.astype(np.float)`. If you still encounter problems, feel free to comment again, but I'm afraid I'll see it only tomorrow.

Comment: I think when I first tried your solution the problem was that I had also included some string columns, but I removed those, and my df is now 5 rows x 44 columns, all floats, with the last column the one I want to return for the 1s in all previous columns. So I think that means I have to replace 4 and 5 in your solution with 43 and 5, respectively, but that gives me a new error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,44) (5,5) (5,44) `. Getting closer perhaps?

Comment: OR not! (43 and 44 was the answer). Done! Thanks.

Comment: Great! For future reference, I added another solution on what to do when some parts of the DataFrame are inherently non-numerical.