# How to describe (mean, median, count, etc.) all two-factor column combinations in a matrix with python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like something like this:

[image]

Every value in a given row is either the same number or a NaN. I want to calculate the mean, median, and get counts for all 2-column combinations in the dataframe, where neither of the columns is a NaN.

So, for instance, the result of the above dataframe would be:

```
AB: count: 1, mean: 7, median: 7 
AC: count: 2, mean: 9.5, median: 9.5 
BC: count: 2, mean: 9, median: 9
```

In fact, my dataframe is about 50k rows long, and 40 or so columns wide.

In case you were wondering, this is for work related to the Stack Overflow Developer Survey. [Ami Tavory helped me get to this point.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35530175/896802) Rows are respondents. Columns in this case are programming languages that respondents tell us they use. And values are your annual salary. I'm trying to determine what programming language combination (a proxy for coding ecosystem perhaps) pays the best. The results will be published in the next couple weeks. Our real devs are busy building real things, so I figured I'd take the opportunity to poke you instead. I look forward to your checking my work when we release a full data dump in the next month or so.

You can generate the sample dataframe with this code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [12,np.nan,np.nan,7],
                   'B' : [np.nan,11,8,7],
                   'C' : [12,11,np.nan,7]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make this reasonably scalable for you - hence using lists instead of doing it all in pandas.  The only good way I saw for doing this in pandas would require a lot of row-wise operations, which are really slow in pandas.  It's fairly easy to add attributes here - just add a column in the array called outarr and name it when you create the output dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import itertools
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [12,np.nan,np.nan,7],
                   'B' : [np.nan,11,8,7],
                   'C' : [12,11,np.nan,7]})

cols = df.columns.values #Columns from your dataframe
collist = list(itertools.combinations(cols,2)) #All combinations of columns from your df

#Create numpy array for each two-column combo and calculate count, mean, median
outarr = [0]*len(collist)
for ix, coltuple in enumerate(collist):
    a = df[list(coltuple)].dropna().values
    outarr[ix] = [a.shape[0],np.mean(a),np.median(a)]

#Create output dataframe
dfout = pd.DataFrame(outarr,index = collist,columns=['count','mean','median'])
dfout

Out[41]:
        count   mean    median
(A, B)  1       7.0     7.0
(A, C)  2       9.5     9.5
(B, C)  2       9.0     9.0
```

Comment: (I think it works.) It catches the single count of A,B in the example, but it doesn't seem to be catching any single counts in my full dataset. Not a huge deal since a single instance is pretty useless to draw any conclusions from, but figured I'd let you know.

Comment: Is it possible your dataset doesn't have any single counts? I would think that it should catch them...  Maybe for some reason `a` is being reduced to a single dimensional np array in your code when it only has one entry, so shape returns 2 for what should be the second dimension (but is the first)?

Comment: Ah, you know what, there were 2 respondents who selected all options, so you nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

This should work (it works on your sample, but I haven't tested it on a larger dataset):

```
(nrow, ncol) = df.shape
for i in range(0,nrow-1):
    for j in range(i+1, nrow-1):
        temp = df.iloc[:,[i,j]].reset_index()
        temp.dropna(inplace=True)
        print temp.columns[1:].tolist(), len(temp), temp.ix[:,1].mean(), temp.ix[:,1].median()
```

which for your example gives

```
['A', 'B'] 1 7.0 7.0
['A', 'C'] 2 9.5 9.5
['B', 'C'] 2 9.0 9.0
```

You create a new dataframe for each pair of columns and drop anything with a 'NA' and then do the basic statistics on that temporary dataframe. There may be a more efficient way to do this, but your dataframe is small enough this shouldn't be a major problem.

Comment: I trust this works with a little elbow grease, but I got an error: `positional indexers are out-of-bounds`.

Comment: On your sample, or on the full data?

Comment: Sorry, it works on the sample, but not the full data.